# Closest Facility Solve Failing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I have a problem getting a large number of facilities and incidents to draw upon solving.

I have about 380 facilities and incidents, that I am attempting to find routes between.

I need the actual network geometry, so and OD Cost Matrix won't work. What happens is I load in everything and attempt to solve and it will get to the very end (99%), and then say it is completed, but there are no actual routes. I have got it to route to 299 incidents and 299 facilities, but with 308, the solve fails.

I began creating a model to run it outside of ArcMap, because I thought that too many routes trying to draw might be the issue, but the model is returning an error.

I have attached a photo of the model.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or what the problem might be? Is the memory just insufficient or something?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0, with the Network Analyst Extension.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Do you have any more details on this problem?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check the "remove bad geometries" checkbox.

There might be geometry issues with some of your routes or points dataset.